# When am I able to setSize of my NMAMapMarker?

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I'm using the Nokia Here maps SDK on iOS and the default size of my marker is too large. The [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapMarker.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapMarker(im)setSize:forZoomRange:) states that I can use setSize to specify the CGSize of my marker, but when I attempt to use the function it doesn't seem to have any affect on my PDF UIImage. The documentation doesn't give examples, but I'm attempting to use it in the following manner:

```
var marker: NMAMapMarker

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    marker = NMAMapMarker()
    marker.icon = NMAImage(uiImage: UIImage.init(named: "MarkerA")!)
    marker.setSize(CGSize(width: 10, height: 10), forZoomRange: NSMakeRange(0, 20))

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


func addMarker(coordinates coord: NMAGeoCoordinates) {
    map.remove(mapObject: marker)
    marker.coordinates = coord
    map.add(mapObject: marker)
    map.set(geoCenter: coord, animation: NMAMapAnimation.none)
}
```

It loads the marker as expected, but it's the same size despite me making changes to the CGSize.

I also attempted to change the size after the map has been initialized after the point has been added to no avail.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

> The [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapMarker.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapMarker(im)setSize:forZoomRange:) states that I can use setSize to specify the CGSize of my marker, but when I attempt to use the function it doesn't seem to have any affect on my PDF UIImage

Yes, its correct behavior for HERE SDK Premium edition, because it has a note:

> This method only affects rendering of SVG icons.

For other icon types the NMAMapMarker doesn't allows resizing as image quality is affected. 
You can resize your image using default UIKit/UIGraphics methods and then create new marker with resized image.

Maybe you need collect multiple markers in same region into one? If so, please take a look at [NMAClusterLayer](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAClusterLayer.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, here is my confusion: SVG/PDFs are both vector base, so the quality shouldn't be affected by its size. It appears that the icon property is a UIImage (from NMAImage), however UIImage doesnt natively support SVGs.

Are there any Swift examples where SVGs are used for NMAMapMarker?

Comment: I understand your confusion, but the PDF format for rendering map objects is not supported by HERE Mobile SDK. SVG and PDF are different formats. 
UIImage never supported SVG, but NMAImage supported. The SVG support is deprecated and mapMarker with SVG icon works now, but it will be not available soon, so examples were not added.
I suggest to use previously prepared .png images for NMAMapMarker and NMAClusterLayer for grouping.